# Does Apple allow AppleCare expense deductions from an item’s trade-in value?

Tags: hardware, warranty

Pretty sure the answer is no; wanted to check for sure.

I have a 2022 MacBook Pro with water damage. Only boots into recovery mode. I have AppleCare. Genius Bar said for $300 I can send it off in the mail and they’ll repair it. I don’t have $300 right now. The computer probably has a good turn-in value (if perfect condition).

Do I have to pay $300, get it repaired, then try to turn it in (if I wanted the cash), or is it possible Apple can deduct the price I would have paid for the repair, and I can turn it in as is, for its post-AppleCare turn-in value, because they know I have AppleCare?

Comment: does it boot in the Hardware test mode -D, or in Safe mode -S

Answer (score 0):

Apple's Trade in program is tied to a new purchase, so you would be spending far in excess of the $300 you don't have to repair the Mac.

- https://www.apple.com/shop/trade-in

If you paid full price for the new Mac, you would receive an Apple Gift Card after your returned Mac was evaluated - and if they received a liquid damaged Mac - they can't use your AppleCare plan to fund their repair even if they wanted to. If you got a discount, the program would say Apple will charge you the full balance if the third party that evaluates the trade in doesn't accept the estimate (which again would be zero with disclosed liquid damage).

Assuming you are in the United States, the $300 figure lines up with the Accidental Damage rider for AppleCare+ for accidental damage.

- https://www.apple.com/legal/sales-support/applecare/applecareplus/us/mac/

I would find someone that wants to buy your computer and see if they will enter a legal contract with you to down pay enough to get the repair and you get the balance of the payment once you deliver them the repaired Mac. You can read all the fine print for the area where your Mac was purchased online at the above link by choosing that region if it's not US. The genius or phone support can also tell you these details if you don't have your contract when AppleCare+ was purchased for that hardware.